# Error adding record. Procedure or function 'InsertCurrencyRecord' expects parameter '@PortfolioOwnerId'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

first post here so I appreciate your patience with me in advance.  I am spinning my tires on having my web app perform an insert stored proc and I'm hoping some more sets of eyes can help.

First is my stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCurrencyRecord
    @SubCategoryId INT, @PortfolioOwnerId INT,
    @OwnerId INT, @ContactId INT,
    @LocationId INT,
    @Model VARCHAR(50), @Version VARCHAR(15) = NULL, 
    @Vendor VARCHAR(50), @AvailableDate DATE, 
    @EndOfProduction DATE, @EndOfSupport DATE,  
    @NumOfDevices VARCHAR(50), @Costs MONEY, 
    @UpgradeDuration INT,
    @Description VARCHAR(250), @SupportingComments VARCHAR(250)
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.Currency (SubCategoryId, PortfolioOwnerId, OwnerId, ContactId, LocationId, Model, Version, Vendor, AvailableDate, EndOfProduction, EndOfSupport, NumOfDevices, Costs, UpgradeDuration, Description, SupportingComments, ModifiedDate)
VALUES (@SubCategoryId, @PortfolioOwnerId, @OwnerId, @ContactId, @LocationId, @Model, @Version, @Vendor, @AvailableDate, @EndOfProduction, @EndOfSupport, @NumOfDevices, @Costs, @UpgradeDuration, @Description, @SupportingComments, GETDATE());
GO
```

Second is asp.dropdownlists where some of my parameters should be coming from.  SubcategoryId seems to be supplied as it is the first parameter, the second parameter which is PortfolioId isn't, although nothing seems different between the two.

```
<td style="text-align: right">SubCategory:</td>
        <td>
            <%-- Confirm from database what max length is --%>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDSubCategory" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="175px" AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SubCategoryValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DDSubCategory" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="SubCategory Required" ValidationGroup="AllValidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right; width: 181px;">Portfolio Owner:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDPortfolioOwner" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="175px" AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PortfolioOwnerValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DDPortfolioOwner" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Portfolio Owner Required" ValidationGroup="AllValidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
```

Lastly will be my c# code showing the submit button click method for executing the stored procedure.

```
protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Page.IsValid) {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CurrencyDb"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertCurrencyRecord", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCategoryId", DDSubCategory.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PorfolioOwnerId", DDPortfolioOwner.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerId", DDTechOwner.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactId", DDTechContact.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationId", DDBranch.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", ModelBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Version", VersionBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", VendorBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailableDate", ProductAvailableBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndOfProduction", EndProductionBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndOfSupport", EndOfSupportBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDevices", NumDevicesBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costs", UpgradeCostBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpgradeDuration", UpgradeDurationBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DescriptionBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupportingComments", NotesBox.Text);

            try {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                labelMessage.Text = "Your request has been submitted for review.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Error adding record. " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally {
                if (con != null)
                    con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Reading this might also be a good idea: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @JamesZ since the OP is using a stored procedure the datatype mismatch which can happen with AddWithValue is greatly minimized. Although I still prefer to be explicit in my code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PorfolioOwnerId", DDPortfolioOwner.SelectedIndex)
```

you're missing the `t` in Por**t**folioOwnerId

So the procedure 'InsertCurrencyRecord' doesn't receive the expected parameter `'@PortfolioOwnerId'`

Comment: :|

Well that was an embarassing first post.

Thank you so much for looking through this and finding that.